# How to create a stack ND C-array from param pack of length N?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, parameter-pack

For the parameter pack `size_t ...len`, e.g. `[len={3,5,2}`, I wish to create

```cpp
double x[3][5][2];
```

or an equivalent type that I can reference to it (cf Requirement below).

## Question

Is there a short way of doing this?

## Remarks

I would like to remain able to make heavy use of "dimensional abuse" `x[i][j][k] == x[0][0][i*5*2+j*2+k] == (*(x+i))[j][k]` etc.

## What I tried

My current attempt is:

```cpp
template<typename Tfloat, int...> struct ARRAY_TYPE;

template<typename Tfloat, int len, int ...lens>
struct ARRAY_TYPE<Tfloat,len,lens...>{
    using type = typename ARRAY_TYPE<Tfloat,lens...>::type[len];
};

template<typename Tfloat>
struct ARRAY_TYPE<Tfloat>{
    using type = Tfloat;
};
```

But I am clueless as to figure out whether this yields me actually the exact same constructed type.
I am afraid it does not support "dimensional abuse".
Is there a way to reinterpret an x of above type into a y of my type `ARRAY_TYPE<double,len...>` ? (That would at least enable me to test for differences in behaviour.)

Or is there maybe even an efficient triple-dot syntax for obtaining the sought type by virtue of a one-liner expression from `len...` (other than with my tedious ARRAY_TYPE implementation)?

## Requirement

For `y` of my type, I need to be able to reference it from `double[3][5][2]`. I.e.:

```cpp
double (&ref)[3][5][2] = y;
```

Comment: Side note : For your nental model. There are no tedious implementations, but there are tedious uses. So it is okay for implementation to be a bit difficult as long as the usage is easy ;)

Comment: Could you clarify what the issue is with your attempt? It seems fine to me. You do mention that you're not sure how to check whether you get the desired type, but you can check that with `std::is_same_v`. Perhaps I'm missing something about your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this? Note I will not use "C" style arrays for this (the final std::array of arryas should be contiguous in memory still)

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

namespace details
{
    template<typename type_t, std::size_t dim, std::size_t... dims>
    auto deduce_md_type()
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof...(dims) == 0ul)
        {
            return std::array<type_t,dim>{};
        }
        else
        {
            return std::array<decltype(deduce_md_type<type_t,dims...>()),dim>{};
        }
    }
}

template<typename type_t, std::size_t...dims>
using md_array_t = decltype(details::deduce_md_type<type_t,dims...>());

int main()
{
    md_array_t<int, 2, 3, 4> values{};
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<md_array_t<int, 2, 3, 4>, std::array<std::array<std::array<int,4>,3>,2>>);

    values[1][2][3] = 1;
}
```

Comment: I agree with your comment. I also agree with your solution in the case of std::array, where it is clear to see that it does as supposed. Now my actual issue that I failed to pose precisely was that I need referencing like ``Tfloat (&ref)[3][5][2] = x;`` to work; since that is how some legacy code uses it. Is there a way to get this out of std::array? (I now also update the question accordingly.)

Comment: I think I don't really understand you but `values[1][2][3]` is already a reference to an int.  Or do you mean you have a legacy function like this `void f(Tfloat (&ref)[1][2][3])`?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by constructing the multi-dimensional array type recursively.*

First, the primary template that creates an array type `X` of size `i`, where `i` is the first dimension. The type `X` is then recursively constructed from the remaining dimensions:

```
template<typename T, int i, int ... rest>
struct ARRAY_TYPE_IMPL {
    using Type = typename ARRAY_TYPE_IMPL<T, rest...>::Type[i];
};
```

With a base case for the last dimension that simply creates a 1-dimensional array:

```
template<typename T, int last>
struct ARRAY_TYPE_IMPL<T, last> {
    using Type = T[last];
};
```

Along with a helper alias to avoid the `typename` dance when using this utility:

```
template<typename T, int ...dims>
using ARRAY_TYPE = typename ARRAY_TYPE_IMPL<double, dims...>::Type;
```

Now you have a type that does what you want. e.g.:

```
ARRAY_TYPE<double, 3, 5, 2> y;
// check that y has the right type
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(y), double[3][5][2]>);
// and even take a reference to that type
double(&ref)[3][5][2] = y;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xoEE4YTf8).

---

* A function that returns the relevant type, as in [Pepjin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77825196/), would be much nicer (since we could use `if constexpr` to handle the base case, thereby avoiding the partial specialization), but you can't return array types from a function.

You should also generally prefer `std::array` over C-style arrays when possible, but if you need to use the latter, this is one way to go about it.

Comment: How is this different from OP's implementation in the question?

Comment: @WeijunZhou That ... is a very good question :p I tend to skip over "attempts" in a question.